# Automatically Disable Default Discover SuiteCRM Dashlet

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

How can I automatically disable the Default Discover SuiteCRM Dashlet so that when a new User is created that the dashlet will not show on the default dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go into modules/Home/index.php around line 98. There are the definitions of iFrameDashlet, SugarFeedDashlet and iFrameDashlet. Comment them out and all new users won't get the dashlets. A reset on users dashlet screen would remove them for existing users.

Comment: Hey @Lawrence I hope this helped, if not please clarify.